# Dark matter without dark matter - review of suggested theories?

Tags: resource-recommendations, dark-matter, modified-gravity

Is there any listing, directory, website or other central resource for suggestions that attempt to explain dark-matter-like behaviour without particulate matter being involved?

There's [MOND](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modified_Newtonian_dynamics), and apparently now also *variations* on MOND, but there are also other hypothetical options and ideas (I have [one specific one](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/337183465_Dark_matter_without_dark_matter) in mind), and it'd be useful for researchers to be able to correctly credit earlier work, identify overlaps between ideas, avoid duplicating research, and see if any patterns or consensuses are emerging.

There's plenty of review articles explaining the different theories for particulate explanations of dark matter, but so far I haven't been able to find a review paper or website listing of proposed "field-based" dm-alternatives. Which is a bit frustrating.

Any suggested sources or resources?

Comment: Unfortunately if you try to search for "alternatives to dark matter", you are just confronted by a steaming pile of twaddle. Finding information about the genuine, respected, scientific alternatives is like finding a needle in a haystack.

Comment: Hi Rob. You appear to be correct. (sigh)

Comment: I searched here "dark matter" because I would like to ask if it is even remotely conceivable that dark matter is pure gravity, something like a photon analogue acting in a grav. field instead of a em one. I am not proposing anything, just want to know if there is anything that trivially excludes this, or if it is on the direction of a quantum theory of gravity, ecc. In other words I would like to know the pov of professionals or anyway competent people on this. Nothing to do with alt pseudo science, a genuine question of mine that can perhaps be easily dismissed. Thanks.